# Evaluation metric in machine learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, data-mining

For a binary classification problem as an example below, how logical will it be if I use "Accuracy" as metric in training and find AUC score using ROCR package? Or should I use "ROC" as metric always for computing AUC score? Dataset is imbalanced.

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)

fit <- train(diabetes~., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, method="gbm", metric="Accuracy", trControl=control)
```

Comment: Accuracy is biased by unbalanced data, you are likely going to want to use  any metric that isn't biased by class balances. `ROCR` is a good package for calculating the metric, do you want the curve (ROC) or the area under that curve (AUROC)?

Comment: Yes, I want the curve (ROC) or the area under that curve (AUROC).

Answer (score 1):

For evaluating any classifier performance the most basic metric/bench-mark is the confusion matrix as Accuracy, precision, recall, F-measure, ROC and AUC all stem from the confusion matrix. Coming to your question, is accuracy as a performance metric enough to judge a binary classifier? The answer is "Yes", only if the data distribution is **balanced**, i.e there are equal number of class-1 and class-2 objects. But if data is imbalanced (as in your case) then it is a big **NO** to use accuracy as the key performance metric. A simple example to debunk the attractiveness/fallacy of accuracy is: Consider *** phone company wants to check the number of defective cell phones it produces. Now on an average there are 10 bad phones in every 1000 and the classifier built never catches a defective/bad phone in the 1000 phones it has sampled, then the accuracy of the classifier is still 99% as TP = 990 and TN = 0 and accuracy = TP+TN/1000. So the best or atleast the bench-mark to evaluate performance is F-score of each class and from there on it could be taken to the next level of plotting the ROC curves and evaluating the AUC.

Comment: It is not true that accuracy is good only for balanced data. Yes, it can lead to a very odd behaviours when you have extreme imbalance (like 1-99), but dataset which has proportions like (1-4-3-8) can be just fine with accuracy. This reasoning is flawed from the very beginning. You do not fit evaluation metric to data distribution, you fit evaluation to **what is the question you are trying to answer**. Never the other way around.

Comment: Actually, my goal is to plot ROC curve and to find the area under that curve (AUROC). As I pointed in the question, after I used "Accuracy" or "ROC" as evaluation metric in train function, I  got the slightly different results of F1score or AUC. I want to know the reason. So in this case, should I use "ROC" as metric?

Comment: @lejlot I wasn't trying to say that evaluation metric and data distribution are linked. All I was trying to convey was using only Accuracy to evaluate performance of a classifier is something that I do not recommended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use accuracy then you should first make your dataset balanced using techniques like upsampling or downsampling.
For interpretability, AUC is better compared to accuracy.